# Cannot find an error in my SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-function

I have a simple function. It has not finished yet, but while doing intermediate check, I'm getting an error saying `Invalid column name 'chksum1'`

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnMidCheckSum]
(
    @MID varchar(16)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE 
        @checkdiget int,
        @tp int,
        @chksum int,
        @chksum1 int

    set @checkdiget = 0

    select @tp = CAST(LEFT(@MID,1) AS INT) 

    if ((@tp * 2)  > 9)
    begin
        set @chksum1 = @tp * 2
        set @chksum = @chksum1 / 10
        set @chksum = @chksum + (chksum1 % 10)
    end


    RETURN @checkdiget
```

Cannot figure out what's wrong. Or may be my eyes just tired from the long day

Comment: Missing an `@`symbol.

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm telling, my eyes are tired

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `@` symbol in the right hand side of this statement:

```
set @chksum = @chksum + (chksum1 % 10)
```

It should be

```
set @chksum = @chksum + (@chksum1 % 10)
-- Here -----------------^
```